# How to use Polly with Refit?

Tags: c#, blazor, dotnet-httpclient, polly, refit

I am not configuring my Refit client using the services in `Startup`. I am doing the following:

```
public Task<IMyService> GetService()
{
    var retryPolicy = HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(2, _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

    var timeoutPolicy = Policy
        .TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

    return Task.FromResult(RestService.For<IMyService>(new HttpClient((DelegatingHandler)myHandler)
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(myUrl)
    },
        new RefitSettings() {}
    ));
}
```

I need to add the Polly policies to the client. How can I do this when creating a client with `RestService.For<>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually whenever you register a named/typed `HttpClient` which is decorated with a Polly policy (or chain of policies) then you do that like this

```
.AddHttpClient<XYZ>()
.AddPolicyHandler(...);
```

The `AddPolicyHandler` [registers](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/HttpClientFactory/Polly/src/DependencyInjection/PollyHttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L31) a `PolicyHttpMessageHandler` with the specified Polly policy. ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addpolicyhandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1))

So, you can do the same here:

```
var combinedPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(retryPolicy, timeoutPolicy);
var outerHandler = new PolicyHttpMessageHandler(combinedPolicy);
outerHandler.InnerHandler = (DelegatingHandler)myHandler;
```

Then you can use the `outerHandler` in your `RestService.For` call

```
RestService.For<IMyService>(new HttpClient(outerHandler))
```

*I haven't tested it but the runtime might require you to set the most inner handler to a new `HttpClientHandler` to work properly.*